# How to read and save data form a WCF SOAP web service request

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I am new to WCF and .Net, hence I am not able to figure out, how to achieve the following-

I want to create a WCF web service to consume the SOAP request and response from a third party application. Basically, the third party application will invoke my web service and will send a request with all the data. I need to validate and store that data in different tables in my database and return the response.

The SOAP request XML that the third party application is sending looks something like this-

```
<Body>
<User>
<UserID>123</UserID>
<CompanyID CompanyName="ABC">A1</CompanyID>
<Profile>
<FirstName>ABC</FirstName>
<LastName>DEF</LastName>
<PhoneNumber Type="Mobile">123456</PhoneNumber>
<PhoneNumber Type="Fax">123456789</PhoneNumber> 
</Profile>
</User>
</Body>
```

I have two tables in database, 
- Company where I want to store the UserID, CompanyID and Company Name
- UserData where I want to store the UserID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, PhoneNumberType

Any code snippets would be a great help. Thank you.

Comment: where this xml is stored ? i mean is it creating a xml file everytime like **foo.xml**

Comment: This xml is not stored anywhere, the third party application will send a request in this format to the web service that I will create and I need to save the data in my database and return the response to the third party application.